# which bug is in following code?

Tags: c++, string

here is  short fragment of code,which test if there is any spaces in given string

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
//performs string operations
void string_get()
{
    string text;
    cout<<" enter string "<<endl;
    getline(cin,text);
    string::size_type position=text.find(' ');
    if(position!=string::npos)
    {
        if(text.find(' ',position+1)!=string::npos)
        {
            cout<<" contains at least two spaces "<<endl;

        }
        else
        {
            cout<<" contains less then two spaces "<<endl;

        }
            }


    else
    {

        cout<<" no spaces "<<endl;
    }

    }

int main()
{

    string_get();



    return 0;
}
```

when i run  this code and enter some string,it works fine,but there is such question,namely it says that there is bug in this code and i am asked to fix it,but i could not see which bug is here?maybe string is NULL?or string does not contain any spaces?which case i have to consider?

Comment: stooooooooooooooooop downvoting

Comment: Sounds more like a lynch mob (or a bunch of sheep!)

Comment: `but there is such question,namely it says that there is bug` Where is this question from? Also, who said there is a bug?

Comment: Even if it is homework he did post code, explain the problem, showed some efforts ...

Comment: i think here is bug and i have found it,namely if position+1=text.length(),but  see this http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/strings.html

Comment: I think whoever has asked this question has made assumptions about `std::string::find` which aren't correct. Namely that `pos` should be less than `string::size( )`.

Comment: If someone says there is a bug they have to produce something that reproduces the bug, or at least give you some description of the symptoms. Otherwise there is no bug, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person who asked the question might have thought that the `pos` argument to `find` needs to be in the range `[0, length)`. This is not the case however, from the standard 21.3.6.3/2:

> Returns: xpos if the function can determine such a value for xpos.
>   Otherwise, returns npos.

Comment: it is good,i did not know this rule,maybe not author too,so instead of downvoting,it is better to post such rules,thanks very much

Comment: +1 you're right, I (wrongly) assumed that a bad input parameter was considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

There's a minor bug. There might be no input available. You're not checking the return value of `getline(cin,text);`. This is unlikely to happen; you'd need to have e.g. input redirection and an empty input file.